# Android filter Listview freezes when softkeyboard is visible

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In my application I have simple `Arraylist` as `ListView` from phones contact list and i'm trying to filter that after typing into `edittext`. 
i'm using viewpages v4 in application and my `EditText` is on `ActivityMain` and my `Listview` is in `ContactsFragment` ViewPager, i'm define simple interface listener to send typed characters from `ActivityMain` to `ContactsFragment`.After typing into `edittext` my `ListView` successfully filters by typed characters, but doesn't refresh until `softkeyboard` is visible and I must have to hide keyboard to refresh list view by filtered strings.

**For example:**

filter listview by "a":

```
adapter.getFilter().filter("a");
```

My adapter implements from Filterable

```
public class AdapterContacts extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private List<ContactLists> categoryArrayList;
    private final ArrayList<ContactLists> originalList = new ArrayList<ContactLists>();
    private NameFilter filter;

    public AdapterContacts(ArrayList<ContactLists> array) {
        categoryArrayList = array;
    }

    public AdapterContacts(Context context, List<ContactLists> array) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        categoryArrayList = array;
        originalList.addAll(array);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categoryArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactLists getItem(int position) {
        return categoryArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
    }

    private static class UI extends HelperUI {
        ...
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private UI UI;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            UI = new UI(view);
        }

        public void fillItems(final AdapterContacts adapter, final ContactLists item, final int position) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new NameFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    private class NameFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<ContactLists> filteredItems = new ArrayList<ContactLists>();
                int l = originalList.size();
                for (int i = 0 ; i < l; i++) {
                    ContactLists nameList = originalList.get(i);
                    if (nameList.getContact_name().toString().contains(constraint)) {
                        filteredItems.add(nameList);
                    }
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            } else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    result.values = originalList;
                    result.count = originalList.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            ArrayList<ContactLists> temp = (ArrayList<ContactLists>) results.values;
            categoryArrayList.clear();
            categoryArrayList.addAll(temp);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            temp.clear();
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your Listview contains any Edit text

Comment: @koutuk no listview doesnt have EditText

Comment: try to use  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your manifest activity declaration

Comment: @koutuk thanks sir. problem solved. please reply to topic for accepting by me :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your manifest activity declaration

Answer (score 0):

**U can Hide your softKeyboard with following code**

```
    private void hideKeyboard() {
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont have any problem to hide softkeyboard, i dont like hiding keyboard until user type and search in list

Comment: please check your question